# Erro System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, stream-de-arquivos

Não sei como resolver esse problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conforme observação do [Marcos Marques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/79734/marcos-marques) este é mais ou menos o tamanho para cada registro no total de 4 mil registros.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde posso melhorar o código:

```
public ActionResult ExportarPDF(ProcessamentoRegistrosDTO pProcessamentoRegistrosDTO)
        {
            try
            {
                #region :: variáveis ::
                string _nomeArquivo = string.Empty;
                TempData["Id"] = null;
                TempData["DtInicio"] = null;
                TempData["DtFim"] = null;
                TempData["Parametro"] = null;
                TempData["CodigoSituacao"] = null;
                TempData["ServicosId"] = null;
                #endregion

                #region :: executa o filtro da tela ::

                IEnumerable<ProcessamentoRegistros> _processamentoRegistros = null;

                if (pProcessamentoRegistrosDTO.DtInicio != null || pProcessamentoRegistrosDTO.DtFim != null)
                {
                    _processamentoRegistros = _IRepositorio.ListarProcessamentoRegistros()
                                                            .Where(x => x.DataInclusao.Value.Date >= pProcessamentoRegistrosDTO.DtInicio);

                    if (pProcessamentoRegistrosDTO.DtInicio != null && pProcessamentoRegistrosDTO.DtFim != null)
                    {
                        _processamentoRegistros = _processamentoRegistros.Where(x => x.DataInclusao >= pProcessamentoRegistrosDTO.DtInicio
                                                                                && x.DataInclusao.Value.Date <= pProcessamentoRegistrosDTO.DtFim);
                    }
                    else if (pProcessamentoRegistrosDTO.DtInicio != null && pProcessamentoRegistrosDTO.DtFim == null)
                    {
                        _processamentoRegistros = _processamentoRegistros.Where(x => x.DataInclusao.Value.Date >= pProcessamentoRegistrosDTO.DtInicio);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _processamentoRegistros = _processamentoRegistros.Where(x => x.DataInclusao.Value.Date <= pProcessamentoRegistrosDTO.DtFim);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var mesAtual = DateTime.Now.Month;
                    _processamentoRegistros = _IRepositorio.ListarProcessamentoRegistros()
                                                        .Where(x => x.DataInclusao.Value.Month == mesAtual);
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pProcessamentoRegistrosDTO.Parametro))
                    _processamentoRegistros = _processamentoRegistros.Where(x => x.Parametro == pProcessamentoRegistrosDTO.Parametro);

                if (pProcessamentoRegistrosDTO.IdServico > 0)
                    _processamentoRegistros = _processamentoRegistros.Where(x => x.IdServico == pProcessamentoRegistrosDTO.IdServico);

                if (pProcessamentoRegistrosDTO.CodigoSituacao > 0)
                    _processamentoRegistros = _processamentoRegistros.Where(x => x.CodigoSituacao == pProcessamentoRegistrosDTO.CodigoSituacao);

                ServicosRepositorio _repoServicos = new ServicosRepositorio();
                IEnumerable<Servicos> _servicos = _repoServicos.ListarServicos();

                IEnumerable<ProcessamentoRegistrosDTO> _processamentoServico = from prg in _processamentoRegistros
                                                                               join servicos in _servicos on prg.IdServico equals servicos.Id into outServicos
                                                                               from servicos in outServicos.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                               select new ProcessamentoRegistrosDTO
                                                                               {
                                                                                   Id = prg.Id,
                                                                                   Parametro = prg.Parametro,
                                                                                   Descricao = servicos.Descricao,
                                                                                   DocumentoHtml = prg.DocumentoHtml,
                                                                                   DocumentoPDF = prg.DocumentoPDF
                                                                               };

                List<ProcessamentoRegistrosDTO> _lstProcessamento = new List<ProcessamentoRegistrosDTO>();
                _lstProcessamento = _processamentoServico.ToList();

                #endregion

                if (_processamentoServico != null && _processamentoServico.Count() > 0)
                {

                    #region :: converte arquivo html para pdf ::
                    List<byte[]> meusPDFs = new List<byte[]>();

                    foreach (var item in _processamentoServico)
                    {
                        _nomeArquivo = "Documento_Fiscal_" + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(" ", "_").Replace("/", "_").Replace(":", "_") + ".zip";
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.DocumentoHtml))
                        {
                            MemoryStream file = null;
                            var pechkin = Factory.Create(new GlobalConfig());
                            var _pdf = pechkin.Convert(new ObjectConfig()
                                                        .SetLoadImages(true).SetZoomFactor(1)
                                                        .SetPrintBackground(true)
                                                        .SetScreenMediaType(true)
                                                        .SetCreateExternalLinks(true)
                                                        .SetIntelligentShrinking(true).SetCreateInternalLinks(true)
                                                        .SetAllowLocalContent(true), item.DocumentoHtml.ToString());
                            file = new MemoryStream();
                            file.Write(_pdf, 0, _pdf.Length);
                            meusPDFs.Add(_pdf);
                        }
                    }

                    #endregion
                    string _descricao = string.Empty;

                    #region :: compacta e faz o download do arquivo pdf ::
                    using (var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        //Informações sobre o GetEncoding: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding(v=vs.110).aspx
                        Encoding nomeArquivoEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(850);
                        using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, false, nomeArquivoEncoding))
                        {
                            int i = 0;

                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_lstProcessamento[i].DocumentoHtml))
                            {
                                foreach (var pdf in meusPDFs)
                                {                                    
                                    _descricao = RemoveSpecialCharacters(RemoveDiacritics(_lstProcessamento[i].Descricao), false);
                                    var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(_lstProcessamento[i].Id + "_" + _lstProcessamento[i].Parametro + "_" + _descricao + ".pdf");                                   

                                    using (var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(pdf))
                                    {
                                        using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open())
                                        {
                                            originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        return new FileContentResult(compressedFileStream.ToArray(), "application/zip") { FileDownloadName = "CPFL Renováveis – Controle de Documentos Fiscais " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss") + ".zip" };
                    }
                    #endregion                    
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Documento");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TempData["mensagemErro"] = string.Format("Download não efetuado! " + ex.Message.ToString());
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Documento");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Posso estar falando abobrinha, mas no `foreach`, tente adicionar um `Thread.Sleep(5);` ao final, uma vez isso resolveu um problema meu de OutOfMemory.

Comment: O que seria o 5 ? uma vez que  `Thread.Sleep` é baseado em milissegundos, exemplo um segundo seria `Thread.Sleep(1000)`.

Comment: Exatamente, 5 milissegundos, é um tempinho pro programa dar uma respirada.

Answer (score 3):

Na verdade existem alguns problemas em seu código.

Primeiramente, não é responsabilidade do *Controller* arcar com todas essas responsabilidades de processamento. Dependendo do volume de informações é importante você criar um processo assíncrono de enfileiramento e processamento em lote.

Outro problema é que como existe um *try/catch* para todo o código, está mais complicado saber em qual trecho essa exceção está sendo disparada. Sugiro você adicionar *try/catch* em outros pontos em que há acesso a base para tentar identificar o local específico que ocorre problema (exemplo um para o código dentro de `#region :: executa o filtro da tela ::` outro para o código dentro de `#region :: converte arquivo html para pdf ::`).

Mas o problema de *[System.OutOfMemoryException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.outofmemoryexception(v=vs.110).aspx)* em si ocorre quando não há memória suficiente para continuar a execução de um programa e pode ser disparada por qualquer chamada de método ou atribuição de propriedade que requer alocação de memória.

Tem um ponto no código que pode ser melhorado onde invés disso (onde você está instanciando um objeto *MemoryStream* em cada iteração):

```
...
foreach (var item in _processamentoServico)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.DocumentoHtml))
    {
        MemoryStream file = null;
        var pechkin = Factory.Create(new GlobalConfig());
        var _pdf = pechkin.Convert(new ObjectConfig()
                                    .SetLoadImages(true).SetZoomFactor(1)
                                    .SetPrintBackground(true)
                                    .SetScreenMediaType(true)
                                    .SetCreateExternalLinks(true)
                                    .SetIntelligentShrinking(true).SetCreateInternalLinks(true)
                                    .SetAllowLocalContent(true), item.DocumentoHtml.ToString());
        file = new MemoryStream();
        file.Write(_pdf, 0, _pdf.Length);
        meusPDFs.Add(_pdf);                         
    }
}
...
```

Use um bloco *using* (para que esse recurso seja liberado via *Dispose* a cada iteração) assim:

```
...
foreach (var item in _processamentoServico)
{
    using(MemoryStream file = new MemoryStream())
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.DocumentoHtml))
        {
            //MemoryStream file = null;
            var pechkin = Factory.Create(new GlobalConfig());
            var _pdf = pechkin.Convert(new ObjectConfig()
                                        .SetLoadImages(true).SetZoomFactor(1)
                                        .SetPrintBackground(true)
                                        .SetScreenMediaType(true)
                                        .SetCreateExternalLinks(true)
                                        .SetIntelligentShrinking(true).SetCreateInternalLinks(true)
                                        .SetAllowLocalContent(true), item.DocumentoHtml.ToString());
            //file = new MemoryStream();
            file.Write(_pdf, 0, _pdf.Length);
            meusPDFs.Add(_pdf);                         
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Correto! vou corrigir e postarei o resultado.

Comment: implementei sua sugestão do uso do `using` e a critério de comentário descobri que não havia indíces e chaves primarias nnas tabelas do banco de dados, no entanto o meu problema ainda persiste, porém houve uma melhora: antes não conseguia compactar nenhum arquivo e agora pelo menos consigo compactar até 1.500 arquivos mas não é suficiente e o erro ainda persiste.

Comment: Então @AdrianoSUV, só com a melhoria sugerida, de 0 para 1.500 arquivos, ou seja já foi bem útil. Mas eu fiz mais recomendações, como coloquei na resposta você tem mais problemas nesse código, sua controller faz mais que deveria, processamento de arquivo não é responsabilidade dela, use mais try/catch para ver onde ainda está estourando o erro e tratar como vc fez e descobriu sobre os índices, tentar processar isso de forma assíncrona, processando em fila, etc, então você tem que tentar ir ponto a ponto analisando e melhorando.

Comment: você pode adicionar aqui algum link falando sobre: `tentar processar isso de forma assíncrona, processando em fila, etc`

Answer (score 0):

Cara, provavelmente o tamanho que você está passando para o file.write.

É pequena. Não sei ao certo qual está sendo o tamanho que vc retorna com o 
_pdf.length. Mas é pouco para o que vc necessita.

Comment: são mais ou menos 4 mil registro eu editei o post e adicionei um print.